# google map don't active when take z-index:-1

Tags: html, css

I want to solve the problem in Google Map when I do z-index: -1 Do not activate the map but the div is above the map as I want ... I want to activate the map with the div remains above the map

```
<div id="map" style="z-index: -1;"></div>
```

```
<div id="filter-div-for-sale-mobile" style="transform-origin: left 78.5px;top: 39px;left: -273.61px;width:360.5px;" class="zsg-popover_arrow-up zsg-popover-adjustable popover-thick-top popover-no-close popover-visible filter-button-popover listing-type-popover">
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the iframe option provided by Google as it is much more controllable in regards to the CSS styling perspective of making it responsive on a page.

Sample of what I mean. (the width and height for the iframe attribute aren't required)

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?zoom=10&center=51.5074%2C-0.1278&key=..." allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: But there are features in Java Script Google Map like shapes and relocition ...complex things I can not do iframe All these things work automatically iframe but I want to edit some things

Comment: You should be able to surround the iframe with any divs you require using a parent div with the style of position: relative then the child divs with the style of position absolute. It would give the design results you're looking for unless you're directly interacting with the Google Maps elements themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It could be helpful to include the position of your element (fixed,relative or absolute ) etc.
Also what browser are you using?

Comment: I tried all the position on the Google Map div I using Google Chrome